# PostgreSQL dates function output to a french language

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

How can I output the result of PostgreSQL dates function as `to_char` to french language, for example the output of:

```
select to_char(current_date, 'Day') ;
```

should be (a french name for a day):

```
Mardi
```

instead of english of day (e.g. Monady)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to set the display of date/time ([`LC_TIME`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/locale.html)) to french, and to query not the `Day` but rather the localizable day `TMDay` using the [`TM` prefix](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html).

```
show LC_TIME;
SET LC_TIME = 'French';
select to_char(current_date, 'TMDay') ;
 to_char
---------
 Mardi
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works on Ubuntu 16.04 Server, with english language set-up

first we need to add system support for French templating with the command:

```
sudo locale-gen fr_FR.utf8
```

then restart postgresql service:

```
sudo systemctl restart postgresql
```

then log in to psql

```
SET LC_TIME = 'fr_FR.utf8';
select to_char(current_date, 'TMDay') ;
to_char
---------
Mardi
(1 row)
```